# Parallelize computation over ensemble with OpenMP

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, default, openmp

I would like to parallalize a c++ code with OpenMP.
The code is not quite simple, but in my opinion the parallelization shoud not be hard, as I have an ensemble of independent systems, and i want to parellelize the for loop that spans over the std::vector which contains the systems.

The dimension of the ensamble is DIM_ENSEMBLE

Here is the interesting part of the code, with my attempt to parallelize. which of course doesn't work.

```
vector<Systems> system(DIM_ENSEMBLE);
vector<double> current(100);
```

System is a struct which contain some std::vector

```
/* do things
...
*/

while (time < T){
/*154*/ #pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(r, DIM_ENSEMBLE, system, current) private(i, max_rate, time_increment, R, j, status)
    for  (i =0; i< DIM_ENSEMBLE; i++) {
     max_rate = function_A_of(i);
     time_increment = function_B_of(r,max_rate);
     R = function_C_of(r,max_rate);
     j = function_D_of(System, i, R);
     status = update_the_system(&system[0], i, time_increment, j, &current[0]);
     if (status!=1) {
      #pragma omp critical
      {
/*173*/ cout << "ERROR " << i << " " << time_increment <<  " " << j <<endl;
      }
     }
    update_time(time);
    } //end for loop 

/* now calculate some averages and distributions from the ensemble
....
 */
} //end while loop
```

Here is a compilation error:

```
  one-node-hirsch-parallel.cpp:173: error: ‘cout’ not specified in enclosing parallel
  one-node-hirsch-parallel.cpp:154: error: enclosing parallel
```

Comment: In your title you wrote [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) and in the question you wrote [Open MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_MPI)...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`cout` is an `extern` variable, declared in the standard C++ library, usually an instance of the output stream class (`ostream`), possibly a template type specialised with `char`. As any other C++ variable, its data sharing attribute in the scope of the OpenMP `parallel` region has to be either implicitly determined or explicitly specified. Given the `default(none)` clause, the implicit determination is switched off. As a result you have to explicitly declare the data sharing attribute of `cout`. The same applies to `endl`.

Problem resolution: add `cout` and `endl` (or possibly `std::cout` and `std::endl`) to the list of variables in the `shared` clause.

Comment: Ilieve. Thank you for this, but unfortunately your suggestion doesn't change the compilation error.

Comment: Does your code have `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;`?

Comment: Yes, of course. By the way, I tried to "share" cout and std::cout whithout results.

Comment: Try to write `#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(r, DIM_ENSEMBLE, system, current, cout) private(i, max_rate, time_increment, R, j, status)` it works!

Comment: @altroware, do you still get an error about `cout` or has it changed into an error about `endl`? The latter is also an external object and should be declared as shared.

Comment: Ok, inserting  `cout` in  shared was the right solution (I was wrong because I wrote out instead of cout). I'm Sorry for this. Actually, after several days of simulation I didn't get the same result from the serial and parallelized code, but not the code is correctly compiled.

Comment: @HristoIliev It seems that endl doesn't fit it the `shared` clause. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that sometimes `endl` and other manipulators are implemented as member functions of `std::ostream`.